# out of memory error when require-ing mercure

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'm trying to install mercure(https://symfony.com/doc/current/mercure.html). I am getting this error.

This be the command I used:

`composer require symfony/mercure`

I even tried this:

`php -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar require symfony/mercure` and I still get the same error.

The error message:

```
    $ composer require symfony/mercure
PHP Warning: Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Using version ^0.1.0 for symfony/mercure
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x00000008] Not enough memory resources are available to process this command.

VirtualFree() failed: [0x000001e7] Attempt to access invalid address.

VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x00000008] Not enough memory resources are available to process this command.

VirtualFree() failed: [0x000001e7] Attempt to access invalid address.

PHP Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1570766848) (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 223

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1570766848) (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 223
```

Comment: For a suggestion I'd trying deleting your vendor folder, then doing a "composer install". This will start you fresh with a new install of all the dependencies.

Comment: Increasing the memory limit won't help here as that's not the reason for this failure, but your PHP process simply runs out of memory that is available from your system. How much RAM does the machine you run Composer on have?

Comment: @xabbuh 8gb....